# Beta App Review "You can only submit one build from version x.x.x"

Tags: app-store, submission

I'm trying to update my app in TestFlight, but whenever i try to do so, this information pops up

[image: Image of information message in question]

"You can only submit one build from version x.x.x to Beta App Review"

Is there a problem? Or should i just ignore this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the latest version of TestFlight will let you submit multiple builds. So just bump version to 1.3.1 in Xcode and you should be able to distribute it to testers alongside version 1.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This message means that you can not have more then one build in "Waiting for Review" state from the same version.

Comment: So, if you are "waiting for review", can you expire the build if you have a newer build you want reviewed?

Comment: I second this question. Hope to get an answer

Comment: There is no problem to remove version from "Waiting for review" status